# Sistema de notificação em html5, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Eu gostaria de entender mais sobre esse sistema, porém, nenhum publicação me ajudou. 
Já sei criar uma notificação

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Notificações</h1>
    <input type="button" value="Notificar!" onclick="minhaNotificao()">
    <script>
        //Verifica e solicita se o usuario tem permissao para utilizar as notificações do Chrome
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            if (!Notification) {
                alert('Erro no sistema de notificação, navegador não suportado.');
                return;
            }

            if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
                Notification.requestPermission();
        });

        function minhaNotificao() {
            if (Notification.permission !== "granted") {
                Notification.requestPermission();
            }
            else {
                var notificacao = new Notification("Titulo da notificacao", {
                    icon: 'go.jpg', //img
                    body: 'Mensagem'
                });

                notificacao.onclick = function () {
                    window.open('http://google.com/'); //site
                };
            }
        }

        minhaNotificao();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Entretanto, eu gostaria de criar um sistema de notificação em tempo real(sem usar o site que oferecem esse serviço). Criaria um banco de dados em php e mysql, com as mensagens, algo assim?
O navegador verificaria esse banco de dados? Como funciona o sistema de notificação atualmente? necessita de um servidor?
HELP, perdido nisso.

Comment: Estou pensando em criar um servidor em NodeJS... ?

Comment: Eu gostaria de entender a logica de sistema de notificação, push notificação. Como funciona? O que tenho que fazer para criar um sistema de notificações em tempo real? Necessito de um servidor? Como que o navegador checa o servidor?

Comment: O usuário não receberia se não estivesse com a pagina aberta, né :( ?

Comment: Não seria util no meu caso, obrigado :(

Comment: Você pode muito bem usar o popkit.site para isso. Basta adicionar 3 linhas de código e o resto você faz no painel de controle. Total controle de exibições para o usuário e design. E o melhor: Sem marca no rodapé, totalmente limpo para ser incorporado no seu site.